# How to Continue Count number of records with IPagedList on next page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, paging, bootstrap-4

How to continue count number of record with IPagedList on next page, when i have more the 50 records at this example.

in Table i count with this code:

```
int a = 1;
      @(a++)
```

and for iPagedList i use this code:

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new
{
    page,
    searchBy = Request.QueryString["searchBy"],
    search = Request.QueryString["search"]
}),

```
new PagedListRenderOptions()
{
    LinkToFirstPageFormat = "<< Прва",
    LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "< Претходна",
    LinkToNextPageFormat = "Следна >",
    LinkToLastPageFormat = "Последна >>",
    Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded,
    DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = false,
    PageCountAndCurrentLocationFormat = "Страна {0} од {1}.",
    DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true,
    ItemSliceAndTotalFormat = "Прикажувам од {0} до {1}, од вкупно {2}.",
    MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 5
}
```

)

Controller code:

```
var tbl_patnici = db.tbl_patnici.Include(t => t.tbl_agenti);
return View(tbl_patnici.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.pID).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 50));
```

Now i have linmited to 50 records per page, and if i go to next page, counter again start from 1,2,3.... etc, not continue 51,52,53...etc.

How to Fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
 I modified COntroller code:

```
var tbl_patnici = db.tbl_patnici.Include(t => t.tbl_agenti);
var items = tbl_patnici.OrderByDescending(x => x.pID).ToList();
var pageNumber = page ?? 1; 
var onePageOfitmes = (items.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 50)); 
ViewBag.pageno = pageNumber;
ViewBag.itemperpage = 50;
return View(onePageOfitmes);
```

Also i added this code to View:

```
int pageno = (int)ViewBag.pageno;
int itemperpage = (int)ViewBag.itemperpage;
int currentno = ((pageno - 1) * itemperpage) + 1;
 @( currentno++ )
```